# Generate the same uuid based on a datetime stamp and an integer value from a json input file

Tags: python, uuid

WOuld like to generate the same consistent UUid based on a datetime stamp and a 6 digit integer value. The json files are sent as events. Hence would like to generate the same UUid for all events connected to the same datetime stamp and the 6 digit integer value in the input file.

Unable to do the same in python.

Comment: The whole concept of the UUID is to prevent exactly that.

Comment: You could create a dictionary that mapped datetime stamps to a UUID the first time they are encountered. Doing so would give you the desired consistency — otherwise every one generated will be unique (the usual purpose of using them).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [uuid.uuid3()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html#uuid.uuid3):

```
import uuid
namespace_uuid = uuid.uuid4() # you need to store that one

# will always give the same uuid for the same timestamp and digits
uuid.uuid3(namespace_uuid, str(timestamp)+str(digits))
```

Comment: Thanks Wups..I would like your input on how to generate a uuid3 from a combination of an integer and string value say id = 12345, Name = Ben

Comment: @Suds that would be `uuid.uuid3(namespace_uuid, str(id) + name)`